# tracked files in untracked directory in github repository

Tags: git, github

When i cloned advimage repository, `img/` directory seems untracked.

```
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git st
?? img/
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git status
# On branch develop
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   img/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

This directory is not empty, there's tracked file named **sample.gif** in `img/`. I try to add
an empty file:

```
gokmen@rodosto advimage % touch img/hede
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git add img/hede 
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git st
A  img/hede
?? img/
gokmen@rodosto advimage % rm -rf img 
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git st
AD img/hede
 D img/sample.gif
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git reset
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   img/sample.gif
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git st
 D img/sample.gif
gokmen@rodosto advimage %
```

`git fsck --full` output is empty. why can't i remove `img/` in `git status` list?

Comment: Heh, my git version is older than repository server git.

Answer (score 2):

You deleted the files from the file system, but you didn't remove them from your repository's index. Issue `git rm -r img/ && git commit` to remove the `img/` directory completely.

What's happening:

```
gokmen@rodosto advimage % rm -rf img 
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git st
AD img/hede
 D img/sample.gif
```

`AD img/hede` suggests you commited the new file `img/hede` and then deleted it without using `git rm`. `D img/sample.gif` suggests you deleted `img/sample.gif` without using `git rm`.

```
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git reset
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   img/sample.gif
```

`git reset` meant git stopped tracking `img/hede`, which was uncommitted and deleted by the `rm -rf` command. `img/sample.gif` is still tracked (and modified) from earlier. If you'd issued `git reset --hard`, you'd see no output here, but img/sample.gif would be back in the working directory.

```
gokmen@rodosto advimage % git st
 D img/sample.gif
```

This shows you deleted `img/sample.gif` with `rm` instead of `git rm`. At this point, you can issue `git rm img/sample.gif && git commit` to remove the file.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i don't want to remove img directory and it's files, i only want to hide `img/` from `git status` output. sample.gif is required for me.

Comment: At the end of your command series, when `status` is only returning ` D img/sample.gif`, try issuing `git reset --hard` and then `git status`. This will discard uncommitted work, so run `git stash` first if you've other files lying around.